# Showing a solution to 3rd order differential equations forms a subspace

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

Let $S$ denote the set of all solutions of the following differential equation defined on $C^3[0,\infty)$;

$$
\begin{align}
  \frac{d^3x}{dt^3} + b \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + c \frac{dx}{dt} + dx = 0
\end{align}
$$

Show that $S$ is a linear subspace of $C^3[0, \infty)$

---

I know that subspaces are closed under addition and scalar multiplication and also contan the zero vector, but I'm not sure how to show that all solutions form a linear subspace. (I'm not sure how to solve this equation either)

### Final Answer

Note that:
$$
\begin{align}
   0 &= \frac{d^3x}{dt^3} + b \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + c \frac{dx}{dt} + dx \\
     &= \alpha \left(\frac{d^3x}{dt^3} + b \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + c \frac{dx}{dt} + dx\right)
\end{align}
$$

Where $\alpha$ is a constant.

Consider arbitrary functions $f$ and $g$ and scalar $\alpha$. By linearity of operators we have:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d^3}{dt^3}(\alpha f + g ) &= \alpha \frac{d^3f}{dt^3} + \frac{d^3g}{dt^3} \\
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(\alpha f + g ) &= \alpha \frac{d^2f}{dt^2} + \frac{d^2g}{dt^2} \\
\frac{d}{dt}(\alpha f + g ) &= \alpha \frac{df}{dt} + \frac{dg}{dt} \\
d(\alpha f + g) &= \alpha df + dg
\end{align}
$$

Now assign $f$ and $g$ to arbitrary individual solutions to our differential equation, we have:

$$
\begin{align}
  0 &= \frac{d^3}{dt^3}(\alpha f + g) + b \frac{d^2}{dt^2}(\alpha f + g) + c \frac{d}{dt}(\alpha f + g) + d(\alpha f + g) \\
  &= \alpha(\frac{d^3}{dt^3}f + b \frac{d^2}{dt^2}f + c \frac{d}{dt}f + df ) + (\frac{d^3}{dt^3}g + b \frac{d^2}{dt^2}g + c \frac{d}{dt}g + dg) \\
  &= \alpha \pmb f + \pmb g 
\end{align}
$$

This shows that $\alpha \pmb f + \pmb g$ solves the ODE which proves that $\alpha \pmb f + \pmb g \in \mathcal S$

The addition holds because the sum that describes $\pmb f$ sums to $0$. Likewise for $\pmb g$.

Therefore, all arbitrary combinations of $\pmb f$ and $\pmb g$ are in $\mathcal S$ (This can be seen by also allowing $\pmb f$ be $\pmb g$ and $\pmb g$ be $\pmb f$).

Finally, $\pmb 0$ is also in the set of solutions.

Thus, the set of all solutions forms a subspace.

Comment: Hint: you don't need to solve this equation. What you need to show is that adding solutions (or multiplying them by a scalar) creates another function that still satisfies this differential equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see that $S\subset \mathcal{C}^3[0,\infty)$.

All you need do is show that if $f$ and $g$ are in $S$ and $\alpha$ is a scalar then $\alpha f+g$ is a solution of the ODE. In other words, $\alpha f+g \in S$.

Clearly $\frac{d^3}{dt^3}(\alpha f+g) = \alpha \frac{d^3f}{dt^3} + \frac{d^3g}{dt^3}$, $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(\alpha f+g) = \alpha \frac{d^2f}{dt^2} + \frac{d^2g}{dt^2}$, and
$\frac{d}{dt}(\alpha f+g) = \alpha \frac{df}{dt} + \frac{dg}{dt}$.

So,

$\frac{d^3}{dt^3}(\alpha f+g) + \frac{d^2}{dt^2}(\alpha f+g) + \frac{d}{dt}(\alpha f+g) +d(\alpha f+g)$

$ = \alpha \bigg(\frac{d^3f}{dt^3} + \frac{d^2f}{dt^2}+\frac{df}{dt} + df\bigg) +\frac{d^3g}{dt^3}+ \frac{d^2g}{dt^2}+ \frac{dg}{dt} + dg = 0$

Comment: How do you know that alpha f is a solution? Also how do you know that g is a solution and not just f?

Comment: alpha is a scalar. Apply a property of the derivative $(af)' = af'$, where $a$ is a scalar.

Comment: I just asked a question on @Cade 's answer. Do you think you could clarify the relationship between $dx$ and $dx/dt$ for me?

Comment: I just modified my answer. Wrote it in a hurry earlier. $d/dt$ is the operator that gives you the instantaneous rate of change of a function at a time $t$ and $d$ is the differential operator. Both operators are known linear functions, so $d(af+g) = adf + dg$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to solve the ODE. Just imagine a solution $f$. Plug $\alpha f$ in and see it verifies the ODE, and the same with $f+g$ for the sum of solutions. Verify $0$ solves the ODE if you please (this is key in the case that the diffeq might have no solutions: see discussion below), and you know the solution space forms a subspace of the vector space, say, of all $C^3$ functions on some appropriate domain.

Comment: "that also follows from the other two" is False. You need to know that there exists at least one solution for this to be true.

Comment: You know, I've had that misconception for a long time--I'm glad you pointed it out. And it is relevant, I suppose, since it's best not to have to appeal to the existence of a solution to show that this is a subspace.

Comment: Well we can spot that $0$ is a solution and then we're off ..

Comment: Thanks! One last question... What's the relationship between $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $dx$. From @papi 's answer it looks like $dx$ is just some function $f(x)$. Is $dx$ something like $h'(x)=f(x)$ and then all the other functions are derivatives of this function with respect to $t$?